# Wordpress reset password email is not working - woocommerce and checkmail does work

Tags: email

I have a bit of an odd issue on our Wordpress site that is currently under development on a subdomain of our primary domain.

It is a basic Wordpress with Woocommerce and a couple other plugins for payments, nothing too fancy. I configured Woocommerce, ordered some products and it is all working fine. I am receiving a confirmation mail from the admin email I provided. Let's say `no-reply@example.com` even though the website is hosted on `new.example.com`.

Now one of the admins forgot his password, so he requested a new one, but no email was delivered. I did some debugging and didn't receive one myself either, even though I am still receiving Woocommerce emails.

So I googled and found the `Check Email` plugin. By default it wanted to use my own personal `@gmail` for the `From` header, so I tested that one, but also with a custom `From: no-reply@example.com`. I didn't receive the one sent from my Gmail (obviously), but I did receive the no-reply version. So I am sure that `wp_mail()` is working.

Which made me think if there was an old setting in the `wp_options` table, or any other table. So I searched them all for `no-reply@example.com` and `mypersonal@gmail.com`, on all columns, every single row. I also performed a search on all files within the `wordpress/` directory to see if there is anything hardcoded (using `grep -rnw 'wordpress/' -e 'tried a couple varieties'`). I did this because because wordpress says the following on the settings page:

> Dit adres wordt gebruikt voor administratieve doeleinden. Als je het wijzigt, sturen wij een e-mail naar je nieuwe adres om het te bevestigen. Het nieuwe adres zal niet actief worden voordat het is bevestigd.
>
> ROUGHLY TRANSLATED: This email address will be used for admin purposes, if you edit, a verification email will be send. It won't get active before it is verified.

When I first added this email address, it didn't even exist yet, now the mailbox does, but I am not getting a new verification email, after changing it to another email on the same domain, to my gmail, nothing.

So I need your help... What else could I try to fix this issue?

**Summary of what I tried**

- WooCommerce works just fine
- `Check Email` plugin works just fine, as long as I use any email from `@example.com`
- Checked the entire database for old email settings which might be overriding anything
- Checked every single file in the wordpress directory for a wrong hardcoded email

**System**

I have a Wordpress install on a Debian 10 Buster VPS with PHP7.4